# ReactJS: button navigate doesn't pass params of an Item

Tags: reactjs

I have an Item component with item latitude and longitude from API and a button, which is navigating to a Map component, where the location of the item should be marked and zoomed in on. In the Item I'm using navigate and trying to pass the lat and lng as params.

```
 const itemLat = item.latitude;
 const itemLng = item.longitude;
 const navigateToItem = ({ itemLat, itemLng }) => {
    navigate(`/map/?lat=${itemLat}&lng=${itemLng}`);
    });
    console.log(itemLat, itemLng);
  };
```

Now here's my button:

```
  <Button onClick={navigateToItem}> Show on map </Button>
```

The itemLat and itemLng log undefined. Map opens, but shows all other Markers, without filtering through them.

```
function Map() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
  const [lng, setLng] = useState(0);
  const [allData, setAllData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  // Fetching all items
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://URL/api/item-list/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setAllData(data);
        setFilteredData(data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("ERROR", e);
      });
  }, [id]);

  const handleFilter = (data) => {
    setFilteredData(data);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current && filteredData.length > 0) {
      const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      filteredData.forEach((value) => {
        const position = { lat: value.latitude, lng: value.longitude };
        bounds.extend(position);
      });
      mapRef.current.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }, [mapRef, filteredData]);

return (
    <div>
<GoogleMap
        center={{ mapRef }}
        onLoad={(map) => {
          mapRef.current = map;
        }}
      >
        {filteredData.map((value) => {
          const position = {
            lat: value.latitude,
            lng: value.longitude,
          };

          return (
            <MarkerF
              clickable={true}
              position={position}
              key={value.id}
              onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(value)}
            />
          );
        })} ...rest of code
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First of all there seems to be a syntax error in your example (the closing `});`). I assume he removed some code post it here.

But as your itemLat and itemLng are defined outside the function body you do not need to pass them into the callback function.

```
const itemLat = item.latitude;
const itemLng = item.longitude;
const navigateToItem = () => {
    navigate(`/map/?lat=${itemLat}&lng=${itemLng}`);
    console.log(itemLat, itemLng);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this did help and now I'm logging the itemLat and itemLng :) Any tips on how to fix my Map component to only show the selected item?